# OCommandSQLParsingException error when performing COUNT function

Tags: java, orientdb, nosql

I am trying a simple query in OrientDB using Java API of count but I am getting exception :

> select product.@rid as rid,
>                        product.brand as brand,
>                           product.description as description,
>                           product.imageURL as imageURL,
>                           product.searchTags as searchTags,
>                           product.name_en as name_en,
>                           product.name_ar as name_ar,
>                        product.categoryID.RefKey as catID,
>                        product.categoryID as categoryRid,
>                        product.categoryID.name.name_en as category_en,
>                           product.categoryID.name.name_ar as category_ar,$offerCount
>                           from Inf_RecentProducts
>                        LET $offerCount = select COUNT(*) from Inf_Offer 
>                                         where priceID.productID.refKey = product.refKey 
>                                           and goodTill > sysdate()
>                    where  user.loginName = 'nooruls143'  LIMIT 5

The exception is

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #911: Invalid keyword 'COUNT' Command: select product.@rid as rid, product.brand as brand, product.description as description, product.imageURL as imageURL, product.searchTags as searchTags, product.name_en as name_en, product.name_ar as name_ar, product.categoryID.RefKey as catID, product.categoryID as categoryRid, product.categoryID.name.name_en as category_en, product.categoryID.name.name_ar as category_ar,$offerCount from Inf_RecentProducts LET $offerCount = select COUNT(*) from Inf_Offer where priceID.productID.refKey = product.refKey where user.loginName = 'nooruls143' LIMIT 5
```

Am I using the right syntax? ANy help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Noorul

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the value of a query to a variable you should do something like:

```
...
let $var = ( SELECT ... )
...
```

See [this link](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Query#sub-query).